# If someone turns down a university fellowship does it open up a spot for the waitlisted candidates in the same department?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, funding

Recently I learned someone who received a university fellowship (with no TA duties) turned down the fellowship and position at a department I applied to for a doctorate. I was placed on a waitlist for admission to the program.

I'm wondering whether this creates a vacant spot (in the same department) or the funding goes somewhere entirely different, given it's funding provided by the university and not the department.

Comment: It depends on how the university has structured the fellowship.

Comment: In my experience, usually the answer is no. Usually getting a fellowship needs to meet some sort of eligibility criteria and it would be awarded to individuals based on their resume and their past achievements. But, if somebody is not selected for that particular fellowship, it means no matter what for this round your application is rejected. If someone else withdraw his/her application (no matter what if it is still pending or already approved or even the fund is transferred to the individual's account), it would possibly would add up to the funding that would be available next year.

Comment: If this question is really about whether someone else declining an offer improves your own chances of admission, it might be more constructive to just ask the department where you are on the waitlist instead of trying to angle the system.

Comment: Dawn, AloneProgrammer - please consider putting your answers in the answer box; answers-in-comments may be moved to chat or deleted.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I am not quite sure how asking an honest question in a forum is trying to angle the system. Also, usually, the departments prefer that the applicants refrain from sending them emails concerning admission status, etc. during the application season. So asking the department is at least in my scenario, not a wise choice. Also, it begs the question of how I learned about these facts in the first place which I am not at liberty to say.

Comment: @AnonymousDuck I think your question is fine and on-topic. Wondering how departments work is important if you plan on spending the next five years to the rest of your life navigating them.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to answer in the general sense. The two main constraints on PhD admissions are funding and mentorship capacity.

Someone who received a fellowship turning down the department might not free up any money, so it is possible the department does not have enough money to accept more people.

But that does free up a supervisory spot. So if the PI they intended to work with has the money, perhaps they would move to the waitlist.

Other factors can include the size of the previous cohorts. If they were large, then the department might take this opportunity to reduce the size of the department by not going to the waitlist.

Comment: Recruitment fellowships often don't last through an entire degree, and some of them require the department to kick in funding, so a declined offer might free up department funding too.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning Good point, edited

Comment: Most departments extend more offers than available positions as well, so if someone has declined an offer that may not even mean that the number of available positions won't be filled by other people with outstanding offers.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily in the same department, but in a case in which the university bothers to have a waitlist and notify people that they are on it, then I would think that is is more likely than not that it will be offered to someone on that list.

But, it may be that people from different departments are on the waitlist, so it might not be offered to someone from that same department. This would depend on the nature of the fellowship and it might be possible to deduce from the original announcement how widely it might be available.

It is possible, however, that, even in this case, things have changed and the fellowship won't be offered or that applications for it would be reopened.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I suppose it could have been easier to answer if I mentioned the university. But I am not sure whether one should do that in a public forum.

Comment: There is no need to do that, and it is unlikely that the answer would be any more accurate, since no one here is likely to be in the chain of responsibility.